# Mutually exclusive concurrency C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing a ray tracer and wish to add concurrency for the obvious (though likely small) performance gains.

In my code I iterate over all the middle points in the grid of pixels that forms my final image to trace them. My idea for making this in parallel is to write some kind of monitor that returns atomically the next point of the grid that's yet to be traced. For that I'm using this:

```
class PixelGetter{
public:

PixelGetter(Point beginning, Vect xIncrement, Vect yIncrement, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
        : mCurrentPixel(beginning), mxIncrement(xIncrement), myIncrement(yIncrement),
          mWidth(width), mHeight(height), mX(0), mY(0), mLock(){}

/**
 * Atomically returns a new point in the imaginary pixel grid.
 * @return New point in the imaginary pixel grid or nullptr if the last
 * valid point was returned before.
 */
unique_ptr<tuple<Point, unsigned int, unsigned int>> GetNextPixel() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock{mLock};
    if(mY >= mHeight) return nullptr;

    auto retVal = make_unique<tuple<Point, unsigned int, unsigned int>>(mCurrentPixel, mX, mY);
    if(mX == mWidth)
    {
        mX = 0; mY++;
        mCurrentPixel += myIncrement;
        mCurrentPixel -= mxIncrement * mWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        mX++;
        mCurrentPixel += mxIncrement;
    }
    return retVal;
}

private:
    Point mCurrentPixel;
    Vect mxIncrement, myIncrement;
    unsigned int mWidth, mHeight, mX, mY;
    mutable mutex mLock;
};
```

I think there should be a simpler way of doing this that I can't see.

My initial ideas involved using atomics in some way but I need to return a point and move to the next one atomically and couldn't think of a way of doing it.

What would be a good way of doing this? If it could be applied generally all the better.

Comment: What do you mean by "good" and "better?"  Note: don't respond with a tautology like "best practice." *State your specific, objective criteria for being "better."*

Comment: I'm looking for some pattern that any C++ programmer can be discern easily and is proved to work in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're really doing is splitting the picture up into pieces, and treating each piece as a task to be completed.

I see two main things I'd change with your current implementation.

The first is that you're splitting the problem into such small pieces that you're likely imposing quite a bit of overhead in locking, communication, and so on. Instead of a single point, I'd consider sending some number of contiguous points at once (e.g., possibly an entire scan line, though I wouldn't hard-wire that into the code), so you can amortize the locking and communication overhead over a larger task.

The second is that you can probably simplify most of the code quite a bit by putting a concurrent queue between the producer (generating the tasks) and the consumer (processing the scan lines). In this case you have a single-producer, multiple-consumer queue, which is a well-known pattern that's relatively easy to do in various forms (locks, condition variables, lock-free using atomics, and so on).

This way your producer becomes something like:

```
void produce(std::vector<pixel> const &pic, size_t task_size, concurrent::queue<task> &q) { 

    for (int i=0; i<pic.size(); i+= task_size)
        q.push(task(&pic[i], task_size));
}
```

...and your consumer looks something like:

```
void consume(concurrent::queue<task> &q) { 
    task t;
    for (int i=0; i<t.size(); i++)
        ray_trace(t.data+i);
}
```

Now, it is true that if you look at the code inside the concurrent queue, you're likely to see a fair amount of ugliness somewhat similar to the code you have above. The big difference here is that an SPMC queue is a common, widely-used, well-known thing that almost qualifies as a primitive in concurrent programming, so it's pretty easy to find libraries that already have them, so you don't have to mess with the implementation at all.

Even if you do implement one yourself, it's still a general-purpose tool that you can almost certainly re-use quite a bit (with some care in designing the interface).

One other point is that you're restricting the tricky code that has to deal with concurrency and locking (or atomics, lock-free programming, etc.) to one neat, self-contained package that's reasonably easy to test, etc. You can also start with a fairly simple lock-based design, and later upgrade it to a (probably more difficult) lock-free design fairly easily with little or no disturbance to other code.

To limit the "damage" from tasks turning out to require disparate computation time, you typically want to start by estimating a worst case computation time. Then you consider a situation where all your threads finish executing other tasks at once, and there's only one worst-case task left in the queue. Obviously it can only be executed by one thread, so what you want to do is limit the extra time necessary for executing that task serially.

For example, let's assume you're processing a picture that's 600 x 400 pixels. One obvious first choice would be to split it into tasks of one scan-line apiece. That gives you 400 tasks. Assuming you're running on a quad-core processor, you have an average of 100 tasks per core.

The worst case that can happen is that all 4 cores finish their tasks simultaneously, and there's only one task left in the queue, so for the duration of that task you only have one core executing instead of 4.

For the sake of discussion, let's assume that the variation between the fastest possible task and the slowest possible task is 16:1, and that the distribution is symmetric (that is, the fastest task takes one fourth as much time as the average, and the slowest four times the average).

So, if our one core was executing an average task, that task would occupy about 1% of your overall execution time. If it had been split up into four perfectly equal pieces, it would only have taken 0.25 percent (ignoring any extra overhead that might impose), so our penalty for using a large task size is about 0.75 percent. Since the worst case is 4 times that, the worst-case penalty is about 3%.

There are two obvious ways to reduce the impact of this worst case. The first is to simply split the job up into smaller pieces. At some point, however, this adds enough overhead (extra locking, extra communication) that it's a losing strategy. The second is to limit the ratio between the best and worst cases. This tends to be more difficult, because in most cases it's not immediately obvious whether a task will be at the fast end, the slow end, or somewhere in between. Nonetheless, you can often reduce the likelihood of a truly terrible case arising. For example, you might use something like a linear feedback shift register to select the pixels, so each task is selected relatively randomly, so if (for example) there's a reflective sphere in your scene that results in a lot of pixels that get traced through a lot of reflections, they'll typically be split up between a lot of tasks instead of concentrated into a few.

Comment: I like the first idea, that it will have a greater overhead due to splitting the load into small pieces. That is something I'll need to test since some pixels can be harder to compute than others and a thread could be 'unlucky' and get all the hard pixels. About the queue, I only mean to use std libraries in this project so I'd implement it myself but I do like that idea a lot.